# What happened to Thoros of Myr's flaming sword?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the TV series, during the episode "Beyond The Wall", the gang get in a spot of bother with an undead polar bear which eventually leads to the death of Thoros.

As the bear approaches, the gang withdraw their swords and prepare to battle. You see Lord Beric Dondarrion and Thoros of Myr ignite their swords. While they attack, the bear is caught on fire. Sandor Clegane, scared by the fire, freezes and Thoros has to save him. The bear then takes Thoros to the ground with the sword between his teeth and injures him beyond repair.

[image: Undead polar bear biting the flaming sword]

After that, as far as I know, the sword isn't seen again. Am I missing something obvious or does it seem silly that they'd leave behind a sword capable of being ignited?

Furthermore, from a theorizing/possible spoilers point of view:

> Is it possible the writers want you to forget about the sword only for Jon Snow/Azor Ahai to reveal he took it and and unveil it as lightbringer?

Comment: We do know that the way Beric's sword burns, Gendry and Arya both realised in the cave that it was magic, not just a trick with wildfire. If Beric's sword's aflame with sorcery, it is fair to assume that so is Thoros'. Beric was returned back to life after Thoros kissed him with fire, fire is within him. Did Thoros undergo something similar during his training at the Red Temple across the sea? Maybe. TLDR, it may be magic and only Thoros (Or Beric) could set their otherwise ordinary swords on fire.

Comment: Just saw the spoiler, it can't be The lightbringer. Lightbringer is just another sword but it is supposed to be strengthened by spirit (Sacrifice) of the AA's beloved. Original AA had to plunge the sword into his wife's heart to forge Lightbringer.

Comment: Also, we know that he bought a lot of swords to Tobho Mott, like one for each tourney. While it seems to be indeed magic/God favour and just a wildfire trick, he did it with regular swords and it didn't last long, at least for tourneys. So not only it is neither Lightbringer, nor a sword that you can fire at will, but it will be pretty damaged, bad quality sword

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is nothing special about the sword itself, its the power of the lord of light that enables his champions like Beric and Thoros to ignite their swords without it ruining the blade.

It is worth mentioning that in the books Thoros ignites his swords with wildfire which has a limited burning time and ruins the sword after, however in the show it is clearly shown they use the magic of R'hllor.

Courtesy of @Edlothiad for [this](https://www.thisisinsider.com/game-of-thrones-how-beric-lights-fire-sword-2019-4) page claryfing a bit more about how Beric ignites his sword in the show; **TLDR: he says a spell that means lords light which enables him as a champion of R'hllor to set his sword aflame.**
Thoros presumably uses the same spell.

Comment: It's an unspoken Valyrian spell. This was revealed in one of the extra clips or interviews recently.

Comment: @Edlothiad could you point me to a link of said interview?

Comment: https://www.thisisinsider.com/game-of-thrones-how-beric-lights-fire-sword-2019-4

Comment: @Edlothiad given the context of the spell and its meaning i am still of the opinion that the spell only works for champions of R'hllor. The spell meaning lords light(R'hllor being the lord of light) and as such it is still his power that makes the sword aflame. Still i thank you for the link as it clarifies a bit more of the universe that was previously hidden.(also you just couldnt resist finding the source eh ;) )

Comment: Who ever wants to be productive. Also not I wasn't disagreeing that it was probably something R'hllor-esque, merely the it's a non-verbal spell that does it.